# .htaccess prevent of redirect if folder name in url

Tags: .htaccess

I have some folders in the root dir with an .htaccess file inside to deny for any access(`deny from all`). And my htaccess in root is:

```
RewriteEngine On

Options -Indexes

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l

RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
```

It's working fine except when I get the folders name in url. I want to ignore folders name and just redirect any url to index.php?url.
Could anyone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `!-d`, `!-f`, `!-l` conditions mean only apply the rewrite rule if the access url does not resolve to an existing file, directory or link. So if the directory exists, it won't apply the rule. You need to remove those. You then need to prevent the recursive rewrite of index.php to itself like so :

```
RewriteRule ^index.php$ - [L] 
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
```

You probably want to also change `.+` in the last rule to `.*` to also match the empty url.

Indeed it seems the inner `.htaccess` files are parsed first, before the `RewriteEngine` one. So you will need to remove those `.htaccess` and rely on the rewrite rule.

Comment: Not working. What about the htaccess file in folders?

Comment: "Not working" is not valuable information. What about the htaccess file in folders? Your question doesn't mention them. So indeed, what about them? I don't know, do you?

Comment: I have mentioned that I have some folders in the root dir with an .htaccess(A) file inside... (did you read that?). It's not working because of .htaccess(A) file.

Comment: 1) How did you change what was before
2) How exactly is it not working?

Comment: I have removed those conditions and used your code in my root htaccess. The htaccess(A) is in subfolders are blocking.

Comment: Do you have anything else in those inner `.htaccess` files? Like `RewriteEngine On` ?

Comment: Indeed it seems the inner `.htaccess` is parsed first, before the `RewriteEngine` one. So you will need to remove that `.htaccess` and rely on the rewrite rule.

Comment: Just `deny from all` and nothing else. Is it safe to remove those `.htaccess'?

Comment: As long as mod_rewrite is enabled, it should be as safe as your index.php script...